# How solve bidirectional relationships on JSONB serialization?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jsonb

I'm trying to serialize an entity with have a bidirectional relationship:

```
class TypeA {
  String name;
  TypeB typeB; 
}

class TypeB {
  String identifier;
  TypeA typeA;
}
```

With Jackson I solve with **@JsonBackReference** in typeB attribute and **@JsonManagedReference** in typeA attribute, but how i can do this on JSONB (Eclipse Yasson implementation)?

```
Caused by: javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Recursive reference has been found in class class xxxxxx.model.Analysis.
        at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:125)
        at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:69)
        ... 45 more
```

OBS: I solved with a DTO but the doubt stayed.

Comment: You can partly solve this using `@JsonbTransient` on the field that you want to exclude, however this won't set the backreference during deserialization - which is a really neat feature of Jackson.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For solving the circular structure you should use @JsonbTransient. As stated in documentation [0]:

1. By default, JSONB ignores properties with a non public access. All public properties - either public fields or non public fields with public getters are serialized into JSON text.
2. Class properties annotated with @JsonbTransient annotation are ignored by JSON Binding engine.

> [0]: http://json-b.net/docs/user-guide.html#ignoring-properties

Comment: I agree with you and @Jan-Willem the `@JsonbTransient` is a solution.